# Android class ConnectionService crash in samsung devices

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement ConnectionService for voip calls.

Registering the phone account:

```
TelecomManager tm = (TelecomManager) 
getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
                PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = new 
PhoneAccountHandle(
                        new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), 
ConnectionService33.class), "sample");
                PhoneAccount phoneAccount = 
PhoneAccount.builder(phoneAccountHandle, "sample")
                        .setShortDescription("sample")
                        .addSupportedUriScheme(PhoneAccount.SCHEME_TEL)
                        .setSupportedUriSchemes(Arrays.asList("tel"))

.setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CALL_PROVIDER)
                        .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(MainActivity.this, 
R.drawable.ic_action_name))
                        .build();
tm.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);
                    if (Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("Samsung")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setComponent(new 
   ComponentName("com.android.server.telecom",

 "com.android.server.telecom.settings.EnableAccountPreferenceActivity"));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        startActivity(new 
Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_PHONE_ACCOUNTS));
                    }
```

Placing the call:

```
TelecomManager tm = (TelecomManager) 
getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
                PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = new 
PhoneAccountHandle(
                        new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), 
ConnectionService33.class), "sample");
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts(PhoneAccount.SCHEME_TEL, 
 "999999999", null);

extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_OUTGOING_CALL_EXTRAS, uri);

extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_ADDRESS, uri);

extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE, 
phoneAccountHandle);
//tm.addNewIncomingCall(phoneAccountHandle, extras);
tm.placeCall(uri, extras);
```

My ConnectionService

```
 @Override
 public Connection onCreateIncomingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle 
  connectionManagerPhoneAccount, ConnectionRequest request) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreateIncomingConnection");
    Log.d(TAG,"incomong call = " + request.getAddress().toString());
    TConnection tConnection = new TConnection(this);
    tConnection.setAddress(request. getAddress(),TelecomManager. 
     PRESENTATION_ALLOWED);
    tConnection.setAudioModeIsVoip(true);
    tConnection.setConnectionCapabilities(Connection.CAPABILITY_MUTE);
    tConnection.setInitializing();
    return tConnection;
}

@Override
public Connection onCreateOutgoingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle 
 connectionManagerPhoneAccount, ConnectionRequest request) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreateOutgoingConnection");
    Log.d(TAG,"outgoing call = " + request.getAddress().toString());
    TConnection tConnection = new TConnection(this);
    tConnection.setAddress(request.getAddress(),TelecomManager. 
   PRESENTATION_ALLOWED);
    tConnection.setAudioModeIsVoip(true);
    tConnection.setConnectionCapabilities(Connection.CAPABILITY_MUTE);
    tConnection.setInitializing();
    return tConnection;
}
```

placing incoming and outgouing from app works correctly

when click dial button in device dialpad (Nexus)

[image]

when click dial button in samsung devices 
Error in samsung phone app : Unfortunately, Phone has stopped

```
D/InCallUtilsMultiSIM: getSimIconIndex: simidx =-1 returnValue-1
05-29 12:43:49.595 31474-31474/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-29 12:43:49.605 31474-31474/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: 
com.android.incallui, 
PID: 31474

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=-1
                                                   at 
com.android.incallui.InCallUtilsMultiSIM. 
getSimImage(InCallUtilsMultiSIM.java:391)at
com.android.incallui.SelectPhoneSimAccountDialogFragment 
$SelectAccountListAdapter.getView 
(SelectPhoneSimAccountDialogFragment.java:154)
                                                   at 
android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2929)
                                                   at 
android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1305)
                                                   at 
android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1212)
                                                   at 
android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
```

Comment: Looks like the Samsung implementation of the Phone Account chooser has an issue (from the looks of the stack trace it must be assuming the phone accounts represent sims only). I'd try omitting the icon for your phone account and see if that helps.

Comment: How can this class be implemented? can you help me ?

Comment: I believe he TGunn means remove the line: .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(MainActivity.this, 
R.drawable.ic_action_name))

Comment: no results I already checked.I think that Samsung removed the support of this class on its application